# Transitive phrasal verbs classification

Tags: terminology, transitivity, phrasal-verbs

Some grammarians classify transitive phrasal verbs into *separable* and *inseparable*. Just for instance:

> Phrasal verbs that can be divided by objects are commonly referred to as being *separable*; those that cannot be divided are known as being *inseparable*.

Peter Herring, *Complete English Grammar Rules*

But what are the following:

- shut somebody up
- stand somebody up
- tell somebody/something apart
- talk somebody into something

etc.?

A third category: *separated*? Isn't it more accurate to classify transitive phrasal verbs into *fixed* and *unfixed*, for example?

P.S. Please note that I know different kinds of multi-word verbs and how to identify them as explained in this thread: [Difference Phrasal Verb, Prepositional Verb and Prepositional Phrasal Verb](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/2071/21738).
My question is to do with the accuracy of classifying transitive phrasal verbs into *separable* and *inseparable*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference Phrasal Verb, Prepositional Verb and Prepositional Phrasal Verb](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/2071/difference-phrasal-verb-prepositional-verb-and-prepositional-phrasal-verb)

Comment: @AlexB.: Please note that I know different kinds of multi-word verbs and how to identify them as you explained in [this thread](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/2071/21738). My question is to do with the accuracy of classifying transitive phrasal verbs into _separable_ and _inseparable_.

Comment: Using 'separated=obligatorily separable', you are looking at two classification schemes: (1) inseparable vs. separable=(optionally separable or separated); and (2) fixed=(inseparable or separated) vs. unfixed=optionally separable.

Comment: @amI: Yes, that's exactly my point: _fixed_ and _unfixed_ would cover _all_ transitive phrasal verbs, whereas _separ**able**_ doesn't include the _separated_ ones.

Comment: With all due respect, that Peter Herring is not a linguist (if we trust his bio on Amazon). As for separable vs. inseparable, this distinction is most likely to be found in ESL books, not the best source if you want to read about linguistics research.

Comment: @AlexB.: Makes sense. Please post this as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: 'Separable' *can* included 'separated' -- it just means that some are optionally separated and some are always separated.